# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Tags: php, mysql

I have become stuck with this problem for a week or so now, and I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. I put my hands up and admit I am not the greatest with php so **ANY** help is highly appreciated.. What I am trying to achieve is a drop down menu that has 3 categorys 'All', 'Fencing' and 'Driveways'. When selected I want specific images displayed according to that category, and obviously when 'All' is selected to display every image in the table.. I have the MySQL table set up as 'image' with 3 columns; 'id', 'Img' and 'category'.

**EDIT**: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home1/wlarter/public_html/portfolio.php on line 80

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

```
<FORM action="portfolio.php" method="post">
 <SELECT onload="displayProject(this.value);" onchange="displayProject(this.value);">
  <OPTION VALUE='none'>ALL</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE='1'>Fencing</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE='2'>Driveway</OPTION>
 </SELECT>
</FORM>

<?php 

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'wlarter_user', 'pw', 'wlarter_portfolio');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$option= $_POST['option'];

$queries = "SELECT * FROM image";
if ($option != 'none'){
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM image where category=".$option
}

$queries=$query;
$result=@mysqli_query($db,"$query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

<div class="box-portfolio"> <?php echo $row['Img']; ?> </div>


<?php
}
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to close the `}` on your `while` loop.

Comment: You're missing a `;` in the line before the `if`.

Comment: deceze's refering to the second if, btw

Comment: The code you posted is not 65 lines long. There must be more into the error.

Comment: Updated code and have a different error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your php code with this, you had syntax errors

```
<?php 

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'wlarter_user', 'pw', 'wlarter_portfolio');

if($db->connect_errno > 0)
{
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$option= $_POST['option'];

$queries = "SELECT * FROM image"; //code updated
if ($option != 'none')
{
     $queries = "SELECT * FROM image where category=".$option; //code updated
}

$queries=$query;
$result=@mysqli_query($db,"$query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
    <div class="box-portfolio"> <?php echo $row['Img']; ?> </div>
<?php
}                       //code updated
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, still receiving an error for an unexpected '{' after "$queries = "SELECT * FROM image where category=".$option" , everything seems okay though?

Comment: I just saw that and added it, I get past the error page now but I am still receiving another error.. 

"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home1/wlarter/public_html/portfolio.php on line 80"  which is while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Comment: might possible connection not properly done

Comment: yup sure, still getting error ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$queries = "SELECT * FROM image";
if ($option != 'none'){
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM image where category=".$option
}
```

You're missing a semi-colon after the query;

Also, the while loop at the end is missing a closing curly brace (scope delimiter) `}`.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

<div class="box-portfolio"> <?php echo $row['Img']; ?> </div>


<?php
}
```

Comment: As an additional note, when PHP throws you an error of an unexpected something, it's almost always due to a missing semicolon in the previous statement or an unclosed brace. Look at the line indicated in the error and the statement before that very closely and you will usually see the issue :)

Comment: I would recommend not juxtaposing HTML and PHP so tightly. It's not good practice and it makes it difficult to debug.

Comment: @shrmn: Good Point! That's literally the first thought that came into my head.

Comment: @W.K.S - How do I approach this?

Comment: I would recommend using an MVC framework like Yii or Zend. You can find some really easy to follow tutorials on YouTube :)

Comment: I'd say that mixing HTML and PHP is good practice, in fact - echoed HTML is a poorer practice. Admittedly the code here could do with a bit of tidying, in particular using the colon form for blocks. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22786269/472495) for why. All that said, using a PHP framework is a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `;` after `$queries` as well as closing your `while` loop using `}`:

```
$queries = "SELECT * FROM image"; // <-- Add ; here
if ($option != 'none'){
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM image where category=".$option
}
$queries=$query;
$result=@mysqli_query($db,"$query");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<div class="box-portfolio"> <?php echo $row['Img']; ?> </div>
<?php
} // <-- Add } here
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```